# How do I loop music in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I  have an 8 second mp3 file and I'm trying to loop it as main menu music. I do this by using SKAction repeatActionForever, however every time it starts over there is a small pause between the loops. This is very annoying since it doesn't sound like it is one long song this way. How can I fix this?

EDIT:

It also doesn't work with AVAudioPlayer :(

Comment: use an audio engine, ObjectAL comes highly recommended and it's easy to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AVAudioPlayer and set the numberOfLoops property to -1 in order to loop the sound indefinitely.

For example:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SomeSound.wav" withExtension:nil];
myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
myPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
myPlayer.volume = 0.4;
myPlayer.delegate = self;
[myPlayer prepareToPlay];
[myPlayer play];
```

Comment: looping is not the problem, there is a small pause every time the sound gets played.

Comment: @SemAllush - Once the audio file is loaded, there should not be a pause in a loop. I suspect your issue might be your sound file. Check to see if there is a pause at the end of the sound file.

Comment: that might very well be it, thank you very much. (I feel so stupid now)